# Log4j2 'Unable to move file' error when using RollingFileAppender with millisecond level rolling

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2, rollingfileappender

I am trying to configure Log4j2 to roll and log files at a millisecond level granularity.

The configuration (relavant parts) I have used is as follows:

```
status=error

dest = err

property.filename = logs/dims/${env:HOSTNAME}/logging-${date:yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss,SSSSS}.log

appenders = console, rolling

## Rolling File Appender
appender.rolling.type = RollingFile
appender.rolling.name = RollingFile
appender.rolling.append = true
appender.rolling.fileName = ${filename}
appender.rolling.filePattern = logs/dims/${env:HOSTNAME}/logging-%d{yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss,SSSS}.log

appender.rolling.policies.type = Policies
appender.rolling.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy

rootLogger.level = info
rootLogger.appenderRefs = console, rolling

rootLogger.appenderRef.console.ref = STDOUT
rootLogger.appenderRef.rolling.ref = RollingFile
```

The log files are being created at the required granualarity but I see errors in the console as follows:

> 2019-06-10 10:57:41,689 main ERROR Unable to move file logs/dims/dsp/logging-2019-06-10T10:57:31,00358.log to logs/dims/dsp/logging-2019-06-10T10:57:41,0587.log: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException logs/dims/dsp/logging-2019-06-10T10:57:31,00358.log -> logs/dims/dsp/logging-2019-06-10T10:57:41,0587.log

But the two files `logging-2019-06-10T10:57:31,00358.log` and `logging-2019-06-10T10:57:41,0587.log` in the error are present when I do an `ls`.

Can someone help me with understanding what is causing this error and how to prevent it?

Comment: Log file naming convention is not correct, It contains special characters which are not allowed in file name. Change `filePattern` to valid values and try.

Comment: Which characters? They're allowed in linux and the files are getting created.

Comment: colon `:` is not valid character. It is valid in linux but not in windows. Java does not support probably due to application portability.

Comment: That was indeed the problem. I am running this Ubuntu shell on Windows 10. I guess the underlying windows is causing some issues because of the colon in the filenames. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was running this on Ubuntu bash console for Windows 10. Although the bash console provides a Linux like interface I guess the acceptable characters in the file name is still decided by the underlying Windows system. The log files are getting created but the logger seems to be having problems rolling over to the new file because of the `:` in the filenames.

Based on Vikas's comment, I ran the same code on a Linux machine and there were no errors then.